# Counting number of grid cells in polygon using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcpy, vector-grid

Is there a way ArcGIS could count the number of 15 seconds interval grid cells within a polygon after digitizing that polygon?

This should appear in a field in the attribute table.

Answer (score 2):

Yes - to do this I would:

- Use the extent of the polygon just digitized to [Create [a] Fishnet](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000002q000000) of the same size
- Use [SelectLayerByLocation](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000072000000) on the fishnet just created to select those that overlap the polygon geometry that you digitized
- Use [GetCount](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//0017000000n7000000) to count how many of the fishnet cells overlap with the polygon geometry
- Use an update cursor or [CalculateField](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000004m000000) to write that number into the field

I would do the above using ArcPy (perhaps as a Python AddIn), but it should not be beyond ModelBuilder either.