# Count number of grids intersected by multiple polygons in layer

Tags: qgis

I am using QGIS. I would like to know the number of 10x10 grids that intersect with each polygon of my layer.

1. Layer 1: This layer contains a list of species. Species A, Species B, etc. Each species has its own polygon or multiple polygons within the layer depicting its geographic distribution across the globe.
2. Layer 2: I have a second layer, a grid of 10x10 cells that I created using:
   Vector-> Research Tools-> Vector Grid.

I want to know the number of grids (Layer 2) that intersects with each species polygon(s) (Layer 1). I know that if Layer 1 had only one species, then I could use Vector->Data Management Tootls-> Join Attributes By Location.

However, I do not know how to loop through Layer 1 so that it does this for each species.

This [link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/118509/to-count-the-number-of-grid-cells-in-a-polygon) seems to be asking for something similar, but the solution uses ArcGIS, and I am using QGIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this (as you guessed) by using Join Attributes By Location.

For the `Target vector layer` select your species layer, and for `Join vector layer` select your grid layer. For `Attribute Summary` select `Take summary of intersecting features` and check `Sum`.

After you run that operation, the resulting file will include a field `COUNT` for each feature that will be the number of grid cells that polygon intersects.

Comment: Great answer. If I want to know WHICH grids intersect each polygon (not just the count), how do I do that?